Unable to run Chrome web driver in Python
from selenium import webdriver

driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\selenium_web_drivers\chrome-win64\chrome.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

After installing selenium and webdriver.exe and also adding them to the path, I am unable to run them. It always says

ImportError: cannot import the name 'webdriver' from 'selenium'.

I was trying to run Chrome using Selenium in Python for automation purpose.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
